# Access denied to System.Data.dll when using LocalService

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis

I have an ASP.NET MVC app deployed on IIS on Windows Server 2012 R2 and it was running fine. The Application Pool is running under `LocalService` and ASP.NET Impersonation is enabled.

But after a recent update build was pushed onto it, I got:

> Could not load file or assembly 'System.Data.dll' or one of its dependencies. Access is denied.

This happens even for that standard Home page from out-of-the-box VS tmeplate.

By changing the AppPool identity to `LocalSystem` the problem disappears.

What could be the cause of the error? Which privilege of `LocalSystem` could be required by the app?

Comment: `LocalService` is really locked down, I'm not even sure it allows network access for example. Are you sure you want to use this account?

Comment: I thought I should be using `LocalService` unless I really need `LocalSystem`. Anyway, the app is mirrored on another server, and that has not been refreshed to the same build and it is still running fine with `LocalService`.

Answer (score 0):

what is the location of the DLL file ?

Localsystem has the administrator privilege whereas localservice doesn't.

Comment: If it's a case of simple access rights, then I will have no choice to use `Local System`. I wonder why it was working fine for so long.

Comment: as i mentioned earlier , what is the location of the DLL , also we you referring to it before.

Comment: It's in a system folder which be default not many accounts are give access. So I will stick to using `Local System`.